# Build SVN 1.9 without dependency on msvcp100.dll

Tags: svn, dll, static-linking

We are building SVN 1.9 on Windows 7 using Visual Studio/batch file. But for some unknown reason (we are C/C++/WinAPI noobs) the libraries we build (according to Dependency Walker) require MSVCP100.DLL which is not installed by default on Windows 7/64bit.

What we have to change to avoid this dependency on MSVCP100.DLL (and possibly MSVCR100.DLL, too)?